# MS Test TestResult Deployment Folders

Tags: mstest

I can't seem to find any documentation on the purpose for the folder structure created for failed tests in the TestResults folder for MS Tests.

The structure is:

```
TestResults
    |
    |
    ---- Deploy_[UserName] YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
                     |
                     |
                     |---- In
                     |     |
                     |     |
                     |     ---- [MachineName]
                     |
                     |
                     ---- Out
```

I understand what the Out folder is, but what are the In and the MachineName folders for?